# How to uninstall intellij idea on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: intellij-idea, uninstallation

I searched much on Google for how to uninstall **intellij idea** on **Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit OS** but i didn't find any solution. please any help for this issue

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After trying and searching more, I found that it's very easy and simple. All you have to do to delete the whole Intellij is:

1. There is a hidden file called .IdeaIC13 in the home directory, it
   contains two files. Just delete the file.
2. Delete the installation directory for Intellij, which is usually
   located at opt/ directory or where you installed it previously.

Comment: Where should the installation directory be present? what do you mean by opt/ directory ?

Comment: Use "Ctrl+H" to see hidden files.

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar what if I cannot find the .IdeaIC13 in home directory? Is there any other possible location?

Answer (score 9):

On a later version this may work:

```
$ snap remove intellij-idea-community
```

Comment: There is no release for snapd in Ubuntu 13.10. The first supported Ubuntu release for snapd is 14.04.

Comment: Helped for ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 8):

1. Delete the installation directory
2. Delete the "config" and "system" configuration directories. These contain IntelliJ IDEA's caches, configuration and plugins

See support page, [“Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs”](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519), for the OS specific locations of these two directories.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me when I wanted to _really_ reset my settings and plugins etc rather than just do a full install. The list of directories is really useful for this

Answer (score 3):

The "config" and "system" directories are probably in your Home folder, but they are hidden and you have to press CTR + H to show them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions, but not worked.

I followed these steps to uninstall Intellij Idea Permanently.

1. $ cd snap/
2. rm -r intellij-idea-community/
3. cd ~/.local/share/ and $ ls
4. Remove the JetBrains folder (i.e. rm -r JetBrains/ )

It worked for me.

Hope this will help someone.!

Comment: in my case there is no intellij folder in snap/ ... is there any other possibility?

Comment: I installed the IntelliJ using the snap store. So in your case, first you have to find the directory where you have installed the IDE, then follow the steps. ..why you have downvoted the answer.?

Comment: o.O I am sorry, I think I missclicked! Did not even realise that I downvoted it. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow their official documentation, they've mentioned the proper way to [Uninstall IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html) depends on the method you used to install it.

- [Uninstall using the Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html#toolbox)
- [Uninstall a standalone instance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html#standalone)

  - Windows
  - macOS
  - Linux
- [Uninstall silently on Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html#silent)
- [Uninstall the snap package on Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html#snap)

  - IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
  - Community Edition